# PHP license key generator

Tags: php, actionscript-3, license-key

I'm looking for a way to generate license keys by a PHP script and then transfer its to my application (Air, AS3), and in this application to read the data correctly. For example, here is the code:

```
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  function KeyGen(){
     $key = md5(mktime());
     $new_key = '';
     for($i=1; $i <= 25; $i ++ ){
               $new_key .= $key[$i];
               if ( $i%5==0 && $i != 25) $new_key.='-';
     }
  return strtoupper($new_key);
  }
  echo KeyGen();
?>
```

The generates key about like this: 1AS7-09BD-96A1-CC8D-F106.
I want to add some information into key - e-mail user, then pass it to the client (Air app), decrypt the data and dysplay in app.

Is it possible?

Comment: Hmm, It's not really that easy, you neeed to have specific data belonging to the owner of the serial to make them unique

Comment: How much data in bytes need to be stored into the "key"?

Comment: @RobertPitt. Yes, of course, the key must be unique.

Comment: @hakre. I do not know how many bytes it will be ... I need to pass e-mail address (someclientmail@gmail.com), current date, a pair of random numbers (to check on the app - this is the simplest test for the validity of the key)

Comment: Make up your mind about the questions posed by Justin Dearing below. As far as you need a **very** basic encryption, look for [rot13](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-rot13.php).

Comment: If you want a UID, PHP has `uniqid` already built in: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: @hakre. You forgot that I then need to decrypt the data with AS3 encrypted with PHP. I still only know about base64 and MD5 similar functions in PHP and AS3.

Comment: MD5 is a hash function, not a encrypt/decrypt type of function. However you can use base64 to "encode" (maybe crypt for your use) and then "decode" (decrypt in your use). It's easy to bust (just saying) but if it does the job, why don't you use it? Please share more of your concerns so it become more prominent for what you're actually looking for. Do you have a problem in implementing that? Do you need additional encrypt/descrypt functions that exist in both AS3 and PHP?

Comment: @hakre. I have the Air app. User buys it. Payment system runs my PHP script and passes a single parameter - e-mail of the buyer. The script generates a unique key that is encrypted: 1. E-mail. 2. Random number A (8 digits). 3. A random number B (6 digits). 4. Current date and enters curr data and C = A+B into a DB and sends the key to the buyer by mail. The customer receives the mail and puts it in my app. The app checks valid email address in the DB and verifies the equation (A + B = C). If everything is correct, then the app starts to work in full functionality.

Comment: What about this: Hash the email address inside the key plus some secret. Pass that MD5 hash to your APP and store it in the database. On verification with the database, return the user information in the response. Let the APP store it for later display.

Comment: I can not understand how can I decode the MD5 hash in my app and get e-mail?

Comment: I need to solve the same problem. So your experience may be helpful. Tahnks

Answer (score 3):

Ok lets break down what you are asking:

You want to:

1. add some information into key
   Well what information do you want to add? Do you want to make the key longer when you do this? Do you want this information to require a key to decrypt? In the vaugest sense thats quite possible with PHP
2. e-mail user
   PHP has a [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function. It pretty much just works.
3. then pass it to the client (Air app)
   Is the air app invoking this php script via a http request? if so set the content-type and output the key to it.
4. decrypt the data
   Back to point 1, possible, but do you want a key or not, and do you care if the format changes. Also, don't you want to decrypt the data in the AS3 app?
5. display in app.
   If the AS3 app is going to display the key, or the decrypted data, then it is AS3 where you need to get it to display the data.

Comment: Thank you Justin. 1.  I need to pass e-mail address (someclientmail@gmail.com), current date, a pair of random numbers (to check on the app - this is the simplest test for the validity of the key) 2. Oh no, I do not need this feature. E-mail I need to then save it in a database. 3. This is all I know and can do. 4. I can use for PHP&AS3 - base64 and MD5 for example. 5. Display e-mail for example

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to store some information but "encode" it using the set of symbols you used above (0-9A-Z), you can use the algorithm below.

The code is an old Python (3) program of mine. It's certainly not fancy in any way, nor very tested, but I suppose it's better than nothing since you haven't got many answers yet. It should be pretty easy to port the code to PHP or AS. The [reduce](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) statements can for example be replaced by imperative style loops. Also note that `//` denotes integer division in Python.

It should also be pretty easy to slap some compression/encryption onto it. Hope it resembles what you wanted. Here goes.

```
from functools import reduce

class Coder:
    def __init__(self, alphabet=None, groups=4):
        if not alphabet:
            alphabet = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        self.alphabet = alphabet
        self.groups = groups

    def encode(self, txt):
        N = len(self.alphabet)
        num = reduce(lambda x,y: (x*256)+y, map(ord, txt))

        # encode to alphabet
        a = []
        while num > 0:
            i = num % N
            a.append(self.alphabet[i])
            num -= i
            num = num//N

        c = "".join(a)
        if self.groups > 0:
            # right zero pad
            while len(c) % self.groups != 0:
                c = c + self.alphabet[0]
            # make groups
            return '-'.join([c[x*self.groups:(x+1)*self.groups]
                             for x in range(len(c)//self.groups)])
        return c

    def decode(self, txt, separator='-'):
        # remove padding zeros and separators
        x = txt.rstrip(self.alphabet[0])
        if separator != None:
            x = x.replace(separator, '')
        N = len(self.alphabet)
        x = [self.alphabet.find(c) for c in x]
        x.reverse()
        num = reduce(lambda x,y: (x*N)+y, x)

        a = []
        while num > 0:
            i = num % 256
            a.append(i)
            num -= i
            num = num//256
        a.reverse()
        return ''.join(map(chr, a))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    k = Coder()
    s = "Hello world!"
    e = k.encode(s)
    print("Encoded:", e)
    d = k.decode(e)
    print("Decoded:", d)
```

Example output:

```
Encoded: D1RD-YU0C-5NVG-5XL8-7620
Decoded: Hello world!
```

Answer (score 1):

with md5 you cannot do this as this is a one-way hash. You should use a decipher method to do so as it uses a key to encode and decode it. There are several php extensions that can do this, consult php manual. You can also use a third party software to this, e.g. http://wwww.phplicengine.com

Answer (score 0):

I found value in [Andre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6515005/5085300) using Python.

I, like the question author, needed a php solution so I rewrote Andre's code as PHP. I am posting it here in case anyone else finds it useful.

**HOWEVER, there are limitations with this that don't exist in the Python version:**

It **does not** appear to encode any string larger than 8 characters. It may be solvable? It's something to do with how PHP handles very large integers. Thankfully I only need to encode less than 8 characters for my use case. It may work under different environments, I'm not sure. Anyway, with this caveat stated, here is the class:

```
<?php

/**
 * Basic key generator class based on a simple Python solution by André Laszlo.
 * It's probably not secure in any way, shape or form. But may be suitable for
 * your requirements (as it was for me).
 *
 * Due to limitations with PHP's processing of large integers, unlike the Python
 * app, only a small amount of data can be encoded / decoded. It appears to
 * allow a maximum of 8 unencoded characters.
 *
 * The original Python app is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6515005
 */

class KeyGen
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $alphabet;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    protected $groups;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $separator;

    /**
     * Controller sets the alphabet and group class properties
     *
     * @param  string $alphabet
     * @param  int $groups
     * @param  string $separator
     */
    public function __construct(string $alphabet = null, int $groups = 4, string $separator = '-')
    {
        $alphabet = $alphabet ?: '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $this->alphabet = str_split($alphabet);
        $this->groups = $groups;
        $this->separator = $separator;
    }

    /**
     * Encodes a string into a typical license key format
     *
     * @param  string $txt
     * @return string
     */
    public function encode(string $txt)
    {
        // calculate the magic number
        $asciiVals = array_map('ord', str_split($txt));
        $num = array_reduce($asciiVals, function($x, $y) {
            return ($x * 256) + $y;
        });

        // encode
        $a = [];
        $i = 0;
        $n = count($this->alphabet);
        while ($num > 0) {
            $i = $num % $n;
            array_push($a, $this->alphabet[$i]);
            $num -= $i;
            $num = intdiv($num, $n);
        }

        // add padding digits
        $str = implode('', $a);
        if($this->groups > 0) {
            while (strlen($str) % $this->groups != 0) {
                $str .= $this->alphabet[0];
            }
        }

        // split into groups
        if($this->groups) {
            $split = str_split($str, $this->groups);
            $str = implode($this->separator, $split);
        }

        return $str;
    }

    /**
     * Decodes a license key
     *
     * @param  string $txt
     * @return string
     */
    public function decode(string $txt)
    {
        // remove separators and padding
        $stripped = str_replace($this->separator, '', $txt);
        $stripped = rtrim($stripped, $this->alphabet[0]);

        // get array of alphabet positions
        $alphabetPosistions = [];
        foreach(str_split($stripped) as $char){
            array_push($alphabetPosistions, array_search($char, $this->alphabet));
        }

        // caluculate the magic number
        $alphabetPosistions = array_reverse($alphabetPosistions);
        $num = array_reduce($alphabetPosistions, function($x, $y) {
            $n = count($this->alphabet);
            return ($x * $n) + $y;
        });

        // decode
        $a = [];
        $i = 0;
        $n = count($this->alphabet);
        while ($num > 0) {
            $i = $num % 256;
            array_push($a, $i);
            $num -= $i;
            $num = intdiv($num, 256);
        }

        return implode('', array_map('chr', array_reverse($a)));
    }

}
```

And here is an example usage, encoding and decoding "ABC123":

```
$keyGen = new KeyGen();

$encoded = $keyGen->encode('ABC123'); //returns 3WJU-YSMF-P000

$decoded = $keyGen->decode('3WJU-YSMF-P000'); //returns ABC123
```